# Can Someone Explain This Code To Me?

Tags: c#, .net

I was looking at this question: [How to implement multiplication without using multiplication operator in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872478/how-to-implement-multiplication-without-using-multiplication-operator-in-net/5872647#5872647) and actually had a lot of fun trying to think of ways to multiply without using *.

But I was left scratching my head at this answer.  I have no idea what is going on in this code.

Can someone explain it to me?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

delegate uint BinaryOp(uint a, uint b);

static class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool VirtualProtect(
        IntPtr address, IntPtr size, uint protect, out uint oldProtect);

    static void Main()
    {
        var bytes = IntPtr.Size == sizeof(int) ? //32-bit? It's slower BTW
          new byte[] {0x8B, 0x44, 0x24, 0x04, 0x0F, 0xAF, 0x44, 0x24, 0x08, 0xC3}
        : new byte[] {0x0F, 0xAF, 0xCA, 0x8B, 0xC1, 0xC3};
        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            uint old;
            VirtualProtect(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
                (IntPtr)bytes.Length, 0x40, out old);
            var action = (BinaryOp)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
                handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(BinaryOp));
            var temp = action(3, 2); //6!
        }
        finally { handle.Free(); }
    }
}
```

Credit for this code goes to Mehrdad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's basically creating a delegate from the *native* code for multiplication, and then invoking it. The byte arrays are the raw instructions, which are then pinned in memory, set to be executable, and then `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` is creating the delegate itself.

The conditional operator is to use different native code for x86 and x64. I suspect this would fail when running on Mono on an ARM processor, for example :)

Answer (score 3):

This code contains the binary of CPU instructions. It finds the address of the binary and executes it. Pretty awful except as a negative example or a joke.

Answer (score 1):

It is assembly language code to implement multiplication.  The call for `VirtualProtect` is to enable code execution in what would otherwise be a non-executable data segment.