# multiply 2 arraysLists together in java

Tags: java, arraylist, int

So I have an two arrayLists that represent two numbers. This is so I don't have to use BigInt.  so for example

```
ArrayList<Integer> LargeInt = [2,3,6,4] would really equal 2,364
ArrayList<Integer> LargeInt2 = [8,7,9,4,6] would be 87,946
```

my goal is to figure out a way to multiply the two numbers and make the answer to a string. I know that multiplying two numbers would need to be put into another array before put into a string so it won't crash with larger numbers. I also know it will be one for loop put into another. But i am finding it difficult to make a code that multiplies the two numbers. the two arrays being multiplied can be any number.

Comment: BigInteger is going to be much faster than whatever you end up creating.

Comment: in this situation i can't use bigInt. that makes it more difficult. I know bigInt is better but this situations its not an option.

Comment: You remember how to do multiplication by hand right?  From elementary school?  Now do it in code.

Comment: yes i know how the issue is making a code that multiplies each number together then adding them.

Comment: Unless you have been forced to do this as an exercise, don't reinvent the wheel... use `BigInteger`

Comment: @user: The best way to start is by writing code.  Show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Bohemian: It's homework.  He's been asked to reinvent the wheel by a teacher.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that this is homework, here is a no-code explanation of what you need to do:

- Define a class that wraps `ArrayList<Integer>`; let's say you call it `ArrayInt`
- Define an operation that adds two `ArrayInt`s together, and returns a third `ArrayInt` that equals their sum. You can do it digit by digit, taking care of a possible carry into an extra digit, so you need to size your result accordingly.
- Define an operation that multiplies your number by a power of ten by adding zeros to the array list. Again, the operation should return a new `ArrayInt`, rather than modifying the current one
- Define an operation that multiplies a number by a single digit. You can use multiplication, or a simple loop that uses addition. The loop would not run more than nine times, so it shouldn't be too bad.
- Combine the three operations that you have (addition, multiplication by a digit, and multiplication by a power of ten) into a simple multiplication algorithm that you learned in the elementary school.

Comment: I would agree on this. But there might be approach to save some runtime, follow the rules of Bitwise Multiplication. You may want to take a look the code snippet presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456442/interview-multiplication-of-2-integers-using-bitwise-operators) to give you an idea how it is done.

Comment: @Dr.Java I seriously doubt that saving time is a goal here: after all, it's a homework exercise.

Comment: maybe, but that's only a suggestion.