# How do I perform bitwise multiplication/division in MASM x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, masm, irvine32

I have been tasked with writing a MASM x86 assembly program which multiplies/divides two 16 bit numbers by bit shifting. What I have so far is:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
count BYTE -1
val1  SDWORD  ?  
val2  SDWORD  ?
str1  BYTE "Enter Integer 1 here: ",0 ; 
str2  BYTE "Enter Integer 2 here: ",0
str3  BYTE "The product is: ",0
mval WORD ?
mval2 WORD ?
pval WORD ?

.code
call clrscr
main PROC
    mov dh,10
    mov dl,20
    call Gotoxy
    mov edx, OFFSET str1
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov mval,ax

    mov dh,12
    mov dl,20
    call Gotoxy
    mov edx, OFFSET str2
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov mval2,ax

    mov dh, 14
    mov dl, 20
    call Gotoxy
    mov edx, OFFSET str3
    call WriteString
    mov ax,pval
    call WriteInt
    call crlf
    call waitmsg

    mov eax,0
    mov ax,mval2
    mov ecx, 16

    L1:
    shr bx,1
    INC count
    JNC DontAdd

    push ecx
    mov ax,mval
    mov cl,count
    shl dx,cl
    add ax,dx
    pop ecx

    DontAdd:
    LOOP L1
    call waitmsg
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

How would I correctly implement bitwise multiplication/division?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interview: Multiplication of 2 Integers using bitwise operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456442/interview-multiplication-of-2-integers-using-bitwise-operators) and for divide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284898/implement-division-with-bit-wise-operator

Comment: At least you should specify your programming language.

Comment: no it has to be in assembly language I'll show you what I have.

Comment: There are an awful lot of assembly languages.

Comment: The programming language is Assembly Language for x86 Processors.

Comment: Really? Well the book that I'm using has that title and it's by Kip Irivine using Irvine32.inc.

Comment: how come this is not showing up under questions?

Comment: Here's what I have for @hatchet for this program:

Comment: @hatchet INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
count BYTE -1
val1  SDWORD  ?  
val2  SDWORD  ?
str1  BYTE "Enter Integer 1 here: ",0 ; 
str2  BYTE "Enter Integer 2 here: ",0
str3  BYTE "The product is: ",0
mval WORD ?
mval2 WORD ?
pval WORD ?

Comment: code
call clrscr
main PROC
mov dh,10
mov dl,20
call Gotoxy
mov edx, OFFSET str1
call WriteString
call ReadInt
mov mval,ax

mov dh,12
mov dl,20
call Gotoxy
mov edx, OFFSET str2
call WriteString
call ReadInt
mov mval2,ax

mov dh, 14
mov dl, 20
call Gotoxy
mov edx, OFFSET str3
call WriteString
mov ax,pval
call WriteInt
call crlf
call waitmsg

mov eax,0

mov ax,mval2
mov ecx, 16

L1:
shr bx,1
INC count
JNC DontAdd
push ecx
mov ax,mval
mov cl,count
Shl dx,cl
add ax,dx
pop ecx
DontAdd:
LOOP L1
call waitmsg
exit
main ENDP
END main

Comment: @hatchet is there any way to attach it?

Comment: @KingszJunkie123 - you can edit your question and include the code within the question itself. That is much better than putting it in the comments, as it allows some formatting to make it clearer.

Comment: @hatchet wait how did you do that?

Comment: When editing your question, select the lines you want formatted as code, and click on the {} button. To learn more about questions and answer formatting, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Is there another way to do the division? like in the example that I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are at a point, where you should work with procedures to keep track of the code. Take a look at this 32-bit example and convert it to 16-bit:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

    First       DWORD ?
    Second      DWORD ?
    Result      DWORD ?
    GetFirst    BYTE "1st number: ",0
    GetSecond   BYTE "2nd number: ",0
    Linefeed    BYTE 13, 10, 0
    MulSign     BYTE " * ",0
    DivSign     BYTE " / ",0
    EquSign     BYTE " = ",0

.code
main PROC

    mov edx, OFFSET GetFirst
    call WriteString
    call ReadDec
    mov First, eax

    mov edx, OFFSET GetSecond
    call WriteString
    call ReadDec
    mov Second, eax

    mov ebx, First
    mov eax, Second
    call BitwiseMultiply
    mov Result, eax

    mov eax, First
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET MulSign
    call WriteString
    mov eax, Second
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET EquSign
    call WriteString
    mov eax, Result
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET Linefeed
    call WriteString

    mov eax, First
    mov ebx, Second
    call BitwiseDivide
    mov Result, eax

    mov eax, First
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET DivSign
    call WriteString
    mov eax, Second
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET EquSign
    call WriteString
    mov eax, Result
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET Linefeed
    call WriteString

    exit
main ENDP

; Multiply EBX by EAX
BitwiseMultiply PROC USES EBX ECX EDX
    mov edx, eax            ; EDX: multiplier (EBX: multiplicand)
    xor eax, eax            ; Result will be in EAX - clear it
    bsr ecx, edx            ; ECX = position of the most significant bit
    jz R1                   ; Return with EAX=0 if EDX == 0

    L1:
    shr edx, 1              ; Look at the rightmost bit of the multiplier
    jnc @F                  ; Skip addition if this bit == 0
    add eax, ebx            ; Add multiplikand to result
    @@:
    shl ebx, 1              ; Increase multipland for the next round
    sub ecx, 1              ; Decrease loop variable
    jnc L1                  ; Loop if ECX >= 0

    R1:
    ret                     ; Result in EAX
BitwiseMultiply ENDP

; Divide EAX by EBX
BitwiseDivide PROC USES ECX EDX ESI
    mov esi, eax            ; ESI: dividend (EBX: divisor)
    xor eax, eax            ; Result (quotient) = 0
    xor edx, edx            ; EDX = 0 (start value)
    mov cl, 32              ; 32 loops

    L1:
    shl esi, 1              ; Bit 31 from EAX ...
    rcl edx, 1              ;     ... to Bit 1 of EDX
    cmp ebx, edx            ; Carry, if EDX > Divisor
    ja @F                   ; Skip subtraction if carry==0 and zero==0 (result not zero)
    sub edx, ebx            ; Subtract ...
    stc                     ;     ... and set carry
    @@:
    rcl eax, 1              ; Append carry (0 or 1) to quotient.
    sub cl, 1
    jnz L1                  ; loop while CL > 0

    ret                     ; Result in EAX
BitwiseDivide ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Would you do the same thing for division?

Comment: wait what do I need to do? I tried upvoting; it did didn't work. I did accept it though.

Comment: ok cool cool THANK YOU FOR HELPING ME. This is my first programming class and so I am learning alot.

Comment: Your multiplication does not work for all cases. For example, passing 2 in `eax` and 7 in `ebx` results in 14, but passing 7 in `eax` and 2 in `ebx` results in 6.