# multiplying an integer by 5 using bitwise operator

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am trying to multiply an integer by 5 using bitwise operations. But there seems to be a bug in my code that I can't identify.
Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define print_integer(exp) printf("%s : %d\n", #exp, (exp))

int multiply(int num) {
    int ans;
    ans = num << 2 + num;
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    print_integer(multiply(a));
    print_integer(multiply(b));
    print_integer(multiply(c));
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:- The bug is in line `ans = num << 2 + num;`

Comment: `ans = (num<<2) + num;` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Comment: ... cause `+` has precedence over `<<`. look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Oh thanks, that worked.

Comment: Do you consider `+` to be a _bitwise operator_?  I would not think so.  Yet if `+` is a _bitwise operator_, then `*` is certainly  one too and code simplifies to `int multiply(int num) { return num*5; }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiplication of two integers using bitwise operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456442/multiplication-of-two-integers-using-bitwise-operators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precedence between `<<` and `+` is counter intuitive. Use parentheses and compile with `-Wall` to get useful warnings abut this kind of potential mistake:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define print_integer(exp) printf("%s : %d\n", #exp, (exp))

int multiply(int num) {
      return (num << 2) + num;
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    print_integer(multiply(a));
    print_integer(multiply(b));
    print_integer(multiply(c));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are adding the num after the change ( num<<2 ) , set a temp value for num .

```
int tmp = num ; 
ans = num << 2 + tmp ;
```

Comment: `num << 2` doesn't change the value of `num`.

Comment: This will work no differently than OP's original code.