# Multiplication using bitwise operations

Tags: math, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I've been looking around for a way to extended a boolean function in boolean algebra into the classical algebra and I think all I need is Multiplication and Addition to do that so
assuming that a,b are two unsigned integers in the range [0, 2<sup>32</sup> - 1], we know that

```
a + b = a&b + a|b    / "+" is the ordinary addition in algebra
```

which is half of what I want, now I need to find what is `a*b`. I tried the following:

```
if a = c*d then

cd + b = (cd)&b + (cd)|b
=> cd = (cd)&b + (cd)|b - b
```

which means that in any multiplication there is third variable I should keep in mind? what I'm looking for is something like this

```
ab = f(a,b)
```

where `f(x,y)` is a boolean function

**EDIT:**
as @DavidGrayson mentioned I should clarify more so, what I'm looking for is a way of describing a * b using a combination of bitwise operators with or without algebraic operators (+,-, ... ) Just like the example of a + b above we can see that we've described the algebraic operation '+' with bitwise operators, so can we do the same with multiplication?

Comment: `*` is a special character in markdown syntax with causes italic text.  Try escaping it with a slash to fix the formatting:  `\*`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplication of two integers using bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456442/multiplication-of-two-integers-using-bitwise-operators)

Comment: @EduardoThales no, because I want to find an algebric equation like the one for (a+b) not an algorithm that based on a while loop

Comment: If you are allowed to use `+` in the equation for `a + b`, can we use `*` in the equation for `a * b`?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking here. What specifically is special about the identity `a + b = (a & b) + (a | b)` that you’re trying to generalize to multiplication?

Comment: Yeah, a rigorous definition of what you mean by "boolean function" is needed, because your use of that phrase doesn't match what people normally mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_function

Comment: @DavidGrayson yes ofcourse, as I mentioned ab = f(a,b)  ,  f can have any operation

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm tryin to find a bridge bitween boolean algebra and classic algebra

Comment: Then I'll post an answer where I define `f` with `f(a, b) = a * b` and you'll really accept it?

Comment: @TahaKhabouss Can you elaborate on what you mean by that? I’m not sure I get what a “bridge” means in this context.

Comment: @DavidGrayson do you mean that since f(a,b) = a * b?

Comment: @templatetypedef a way of describing boolean operators using algebra (*,-,+...)

Comment: You need to specify very precisely what kind of answer you are looking for or else this will get closed.  It sounds like you are looking for a function `f` that takes two arguments and yields the product of them, so why can't I just answer your question with `f(a, b) = a * b` and thus solve your problem?

Comment: @DavidGrayson you're right I'll edit the post

Comment: `a + b = a&b + a|b` doesn't really accomplish anything. You are "simplifying" addition by replacing it with some bitwise operations and... another addition. Why not "simplify" to `a + b = (a|a) + (b|b)`?

Comment: @RaymondChen that's what i'm trying to do, I'm trying to replace addition with bitwise operations that could link a and b with bitwise operator

Comment: I’m sorry, I still don’t understand what you’re asking for here. The original equality you’re mentioning with addition doesn’t replace addition with a simpler operation, and is just an identity that involves addition in two different contexts. What specific insights does that provide that you’d like to replicate with multiplication?

Comment: start with 1bit*1bit , then 2bit*2bit ... using Karnaugh maps to get boolean algebra result only ... however for 32bit * 32bit the stuff will be very complicated ... that is not how its done in real HW ... usually boolean algebra is combined with arithmetic addition in a sequencial automat like Shift and Add or binary long multiplication ... as mentioned before defining operator with the same operator is nonsense ... and would lead to stack overflow if coded like that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea why you are asking this question, but you specified that you are looking for

> a way of describing a * b using a combination of bitwise operators with or without algebraic operators

You also explicitly said in the comments that `*` is an algebraic operator we are allowed to use.

Later, you added that there must be a boolean operator linking a and b.

So I will answer your question by saying:

`a * b = (a | (0 & (a | b))) * (b | 0)`

This is a formula for `a * b` that uses bitwise operators so it meets all your conditions.

Comment: in this sense we could also say that a + b = (a | 0) + (b | 0) instead of a + b = a&b + a|b maybe I couldn't clarifying my question enough but (a|0) is just (a), also there is not boolean operator linking a and b somehow instead it's just the algebraic operator *

Comment: You keep changing the goal posts.

Comment: I modified my answer so it includes `a | b`.  I could similarly modify it to include `a OP b` for any binary operator you want.  Please click the checkmark.

Comment: my goal is to find something like this a * b = a&b + .. + a|b .. what you're doing is just adding and subtracting like a = a + b - b you're equation is reversible to it's original form just a step ahead

Comment: that "0" in you're equation doesn't match my conditions

Comment: If you're changing the goalposts yet again then I can replace `0` with `a & ~a` but that seems pointless, you'll just make up another rule after I do that.

Comment: I think you're trying to look for a function that has the same aesthetics as `(a | b) + (a & b)` but aesthetics are opinion-based and not suitable for StackOverflow.  Maybe try on a Math reddit group or something.

Comment: yes you're right, will do. thank you ^^